# 最後に出現する半角英数文字を正規表現で取り出したい

Tags: 正規表現

正規表現に関する質問です。

■概要
「そうですねabcの次はdefですね笑」

上記文章のdefにマッチさせる正規表現文字列をご教授下さい。

■ロジック
`***笑` の `***` の中に存在する「最後の」半角英数文字を取り出したい。

■現在の正規表現文字列
`([0-9a-zA-Z!-~]+)(.*)(笑)`

■現在の正規表現文字列に対するマッチ結果
マッチ文字列 : abcの次はdefですね笑
マッチ文字列グループ1 : abc
マッチ文字列グループ2 : の次はdefですね
マッチ文字列グループ3 : 笑

■質問内容
上記グループのいずれかにdefが該当するような
正規表現文字列を教えて下さい。
ポイントは「最後の」です。

Comment: 以下で解決しました。ご回答ありがとうございます。
"([0-9a-zA-Z!-~]+)([^0-9a-zA-Z!-~]*)(笑)"

Answer (score 3):

> ([0-9a-zA-Z!-~]+)(.*)(笑)

上記の`(.*)`を`[0-9a-zA-Z!-~]`の否定である`([^0-9a-zA-Z!-~]*)`に変えれば良いのでは。

Comment: 以下で解決しました。ご回答ありがとうございます。
"([0-9a-zA-Z!-~]+)([^0-9a-zA-Z!-~]*)(笑)"

Comment: @困った よろしければ回答の左側にあるチェックマークをクリックして頂けると、解決済みという目印になります。